# How can I implement multi-node barrier in Java?

Tags: java, distributed-computing

I am building a multi-node (distributed) experiment setup in Java for academic project. I use a script to start the application at all the nodes. After the application starts and gets all the modules up, these nodes start some operations on shared data distributed over these nodes. Currently I have put a delay between the instant all modules are up and the instant when the first operation is initiated at an individual node. Though this seems to work, I would like to have a barrier such that all nodes start their modules and progress to the barrier. Once all nodes have progressed to the barrier, then they can initiate operation on shared data.

It would be a great help, if someone can either explain how to do it or at least point me to a right documentation. FYI, I would prefer to avoid semaphores if possible. At the start I know the number of nodes participating in the experiment, so this information of #nodes can be used in setting up the barrier.

Thanks
Sachin

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Hazelcast. There is a [CyclicBarrier implementation](https://code.google.com/p/hazelcast/issues/detail?id=435) available (I did not test it). You could also use a distributed version of a [CountDownLatch](http://www.hazelcast.org/docs/1.9.4/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/ICountDownLatch.html).